# Why can't students master math simply by passive reading?

Tags: students-mistakes

Yearly, at least one student emails me this question, after wholly relying on passive reading then failing the exam. They successfully remember and can regurgitate everything from the textbook and lectures; can compute a question if analogous enough to something déjà vu, and something they saw before; and can prove straightforward corollaries. But they can't answer unseen, new-fashioned questions or trickier computations. They wholly fail to prove more abstract results.

> Students tend to *prefer* passive studying **because it's easier and more comfortable**. In fact, [this Harvard study](https://www.pnas.org/content/pnas/early/2019/09/03/1821936116.full.pdf) shows that most students even convince themselves that passive methods are more effective, and that lecturing professors provide "better learning" than professors who engage students in-class projects, even though those hands-on projects ultimately provide much deeper education than traditional passive methods. [[Source]](https://www.brainscape.com/academy/active-studying-vs-passive-studying/)

#### But why precisely does passive study fail for learning math? Why can't math students simply read multiple textbooks on the same subject + DETAILED FULL solutions to exercises and problems, in lieu of picking up a writing implement and plugging away at exercises?

I am seeking explanations more detailed, scholarly, and specific to math than [this](https://www.leonardoenglish.com/blog/passive-language-learning-is-bullshit).

> The reason is that learning is not a passive activity. As [some researchers](http://mjltm.org/files/site1/user_files_a9608a/admin-A-10-1-23-7c58f0c.pdf#page=125) have stated,
>
> *“Students cannot learn just by attending the classes, listening to teachers, memorising ready-made assignments, and producing answers. They must talk about what they are learning (output), write about it (integration), connect it to past knowledge, and use it in their daily lives. They must make what they learn part of their lives by practice.”*
>
> The problem with passive learning is that you [don’t engage with the information you receive.](https://universeofmemory.com/optimize-your-language-learning/) And that means you don’t learn it as well.

> This is not always so when recalling facts in a self-test—more effort is often required to bring the facts to mind, so they don’t seem as solid. From a student’s point of view, it can seem obvious which method—restudying—produces better learning. Robert Bjork refers to this as an “illusion of competence” after restudying. The student concludes that she knows the material well based on the confident mastery she feels at that moment.
>
> And she expects that the same mastery will be there several days later when the exam takes place. But this is unlikely. The same illusion of competence is at work during cramming, when the facts feel secure and firmly grasped. While that is indeed true at the time, it’s a mistake to assume that long-lasting memory strength has been created. - [Robert Madigan - How Memory Works](https://books.google.pl/books/about/How_Memory_Works_and_How_to_Make_It_Work.html?id=R3T3CQAAQBAJ&redir_esc=y).

Comment: Why can't you read about how to throw a basketball (and play the game) and then do it? Because your body builds muscle memory. With math, new neural connections are made. It sounds like you've found some good references for this. I don't don't know of others off-hand.

Comment: Could you please try to clarify the following points? (i) How does your question differ from the [one you previously asked](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/25792/16250)? (ii) What is specific about math education in your question? One can't learn anything non-trivial to a reasonable level by passive methods alone (reading a list of traffic rules doesn't enable people to savely engage in traffic; learning vocabulary and grammar won't suffice for anyone to speak a new language; merely studying anatomy books won't make you a surgeon).

Comment: (iii) What precisely do you mean by "why" in the question? Are you looking for a neuropsychological explanation of the observation that the human brain isn't able to learn non-trivial things without engaging them actively?

Comment: @SueVanHattum But basketball is a physical sport and requires "muscle memory". Math doesn't?

Comment: @JochenGlueck (i) Just because passive reading fails, doesn't mean that students need to solve problems. Some students have actively read the textbook and lecture notes, but they didn't solve any end of chapter exercises and questions. (ii) I am trying to focus on math. Perhaps the answer can be generalized. (iii) I am seeking any explanation, including neuropsychological.

Comment: "They successfully remember and can regurgitate everything from the textbook and lectures; can compute a question if analogous enough to something déjà vu, and something they saw before; and can prove straightforward corollaries." -- I find it hard to believe they can do even this much just by passive reading without practice. Even in memorization-intensive areas of study there is evidence that [spaced retrieval practice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaced_repetition) is necessary. It seems to me that your students must be doing something non-passive if they are getting as far as you say.

Comment: Your question reminds me of the following short story that I saw when I started  learning calculus. “Peter wanted to know the names of the birds. He read a book about birds and learned their names. Peter wanted to know how to swim. He read a book on swimming and then drowned.”

Comment: @user131533 the earliest source I know is *Studying Freshman Calculus: Exercises and Sample Exams* by Basar, Bonic, DuCasse, Krantz, and Lipschutz, D. R. Heath and Co., Lexington, MA, 1976.  I don't have a copy with me, so I can't say the page where it appears. It was later used on the first page of the bibliography of *Experiencing Geometry: Euclidean and Non-Euclidean with History* by Henderson and Taimina, 4th ed., 2020 (maybe earlier editions too). A copy of the geometry book online gave me the information about Bonic's book.

Comment: A reference to Bonic's book is also at the top of the page https://w3.fiu.edu/rameau/mdc_mac2311_index.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the goal of learning mathematics would be to retain certain information, then passive reading would work, albeit still be a supoptimal learning strategy.

But this isn't the goal. The goal is to **adjust how we think**. It seems kind of obvious to me that this will require extensive attempts to think in the new way.